# Calculus residue options

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I try to calculate first

```
f[z_]:=\[Pi](Cot[\[Pi] z])
Simplify[-Tr[Table[Expand[Residue[(f[z]),{z,l },Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers]],{l,{k}}]],Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers]
```

and get -1 perfect but when change the function

```
f[z_]:=(EulerGamma-PolyGamma[z])^2
Simplify[-Tr[Table[Expand[Residue[(f[z]),{z,l },Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers]],{l,{-k}}]],Assumptions->k\[Element]Integers]
```

we get 0 when the correct result must be (k+1)-(k+2)EulerGamma
Must be something to declare to the function First i do not 
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to include the sign in the assumptions to [`Residue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue):

```
Residue[
    (EulerGamma-PolyGamma[z])^2,
    {z, k},
    Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers && k<0
]
```

> 2 (2 EulerGamma - HarmonicNumber[-k])